# openfoam C++ operator& override

Tags: c++, overriding, openfoam

```
template<class Type>
tmp<GeometricField<Type, fvPatchField, volMesh>> operator&
(
   const fvMatrix<Type>&,
   const tmp<GeometricField<Type, fvPatchField, volMesh>>&
);
```

Could anyone help me understand this override function in OpenFoam? As we know, operator& override should not have two parameters. So, I am confused. And do anyone know how to use this override function? Please give me a simple example, if you are not busy? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As we know, `operator&` override should not have two parameters.

Not true.

The unary `operator&` and the binary `operator&` have two different meanings.

The unary `operator&` is the equivalent of the [address-of operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) while the binary `operator&` is the equivalent of the [bitwise AND operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators).

For reasons that are not obvious to me, the posted code defines an overload of the binary `&` operator between a `fvMatrix<Type>` and a `tmp<GeometricField<Type, fvPatchField, volMesh>>`.

Syntactically speaking, the usage would be:

```
fvMatrix<Type> var1{};
tmp<GeometricField<Type, fvPatchField, volMesh>> var2{};

auto var3 = var1 & var2;
```

Comment: @刘雄国, I am not sure what you are trying to say in the comment.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Now I get it. That's a great help.